# How can i get the profile picture using facebook sdk for android?

Tags: facebook

I'm wondering if i can get the profile picture with the user properties or something. I need the name, last name, email and profile picture. Name, last name and email is easy. Could anyone give me a tip? Or maybe is it impossible?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the `/user/picture` connection. It's great.

You can read about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/

Comment: Thanks bro!! I will investigate it!! ;)